# Floating point calculations (double, vs2015, C ++, sdk 8.1) give incorrect results on XEON

Tags: visual-studio-2015, double

C ++ code, mostly double calculations.
Everything worked fine until the same projects recompiled for 2015 64 bit with SDK 8.1. We began to get DIFFERENT results when we run on XEONs, on i7 and i5 everything is the same.
Someone came across?

Comment: What are the floating-point settings for your projects? (In "Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Floating Pojnt Model".) If this value is set to "fast" then you may have issues between chipsets. Make sure it is either "precise" or "strict".

Comment: Oh, sorry. I failed to point it out. Enable Enhanced Instruction Set, Floating Point Model, Enable Floating Point Exceptions ARE ALL set by DEFAULT.

Comment: Seems like a [known issue](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/Difference-of-calculcation-result-between-i7-and-xeon-cpu/td-p/1015638). Maybe try setting the "Floating Point Model" to "Strict"?